# Getting bufferedReader.readLine() value is null in android

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, readline

Working condition :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l /etc/");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
Log.d(TAG,"bufferedReader.readLine()===>"+bufferedReader.readLine());
```

Snipped log : bufferedReader.readLine()===>total 7580

not working :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./etc/lighttpd -D -f /etc/test.conf");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
Log.d(TAG,"bufferedReader.readLine()===>"+bufferedReader.readLine());
```

Snipped log : bufferedReader.readLine()===>null

Can you please help me, why I am receiving bufferedReader.readLine() is "null" while execute "./etc/lighttpd -D -f /etc/test.conf" command

executed below command in device shell :

```
#./etc/lighttpd -D -f /etc/test.conf
2022-08-30 12:38:18: server.c.1508) server started (lighttpd/1.4.58)
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in `/etc/lighttpd`. Probably it tries to write something in `/var/tmp` and finishes work.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have done some changes in configfile.c file and "exist: /var/tmp " line is not coming , but still I am getting null value. I have updated my question , can you please check

Comment: Thanks! What text do you receive in the first case? I wonder what difference can be. Sorry, but I didn't work with lighttpd.

Comment: "total 7580" is the first line of "ls -l /etc/" .

Comment: You can debug the app. For instance, check that `process.getInputStream()` returns something valid.

Comment: yes i tried , Log.d(TAG, "test===> process.getInputStream()"+process.getInputStream()); ===>response===>  test===> process.getInputStream()java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@6eb2e7b

Comment: process.getInputStream() returns `InputStream` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). Probably you can detect how much data can be read with `available()` method.

Comment: `readLine()` returns null at end of stream. This is documented. If it happens on the first call, the conclusion is that the input was empty. What was the value returned by `process.waitFor()`?

Comment: @CoolMind No. `available()` only tells you how much data can be read *without blocking*. Either way, it doesn't get you anywhere. The input will still be empty.

Comment: @user207421, thanks, agree with you. I think the service doesn't output anything.

Comment: The use of a relative pathname (i.e. `./etc/lighthttpd`) means that you might be running a different executable from Java and from the command line.  Depending on the JVM and shell's respective working directories.   (But I'd have expected `exec` to throw an exception ...)

Answer (score 0):

The pathname `./etc/lighttpd` is suspicious, but the evidence you have show us proves that:

1. it is present, and
2. it is executable,

... at least for some current directory.

Why do I say that it is proven?  Because:

1. `exec` didn't throw an `IOException`, and
2. you showed us the output from running the same command from the command line.

Admittedly, it is possible that the current directories are different ... which is one of the reasons that I said that `./etc/lighttpd` is suspicious!

---

So if the problem is not that `./etc/lighttpd` is not an executable, **what is the explanation** for `bufferedReader.readLine()` returning `null`?

Well, the simplest theory is that `lighttpd` is writing to standard error rather than standard output, and that it has **closed** its standard output.   That would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Anyhow ... my suggestions would be:

1. Change  `./etc/lighttpd` to the **absolute** pathname for the executable that you are using ... to remove any doubt.
2. Try opening and reading from `process.getErrorStream()` instead.
3. Look in the `lighttpd` log file for any errors.

---

Finally, you have tagged your question with `[android]` but AFAIK there is no (official) Android port for Lighttpd.  I am guessing that the tag was a mistake because there is no other mention of Android.  But if it was not a mistake, you should tell us where you go the Android port from.  That *may* help people to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`/etc/lighttpd` is usually a directory containing configuration information.  `/etc/lighttpd` is often not an executable.

Comment: But `./etc/lighthttpd` and `/etc/lighthttpd` could be different objects.  Depending on what `.` currently is.   I think this (^^^) is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Stephen C, I am a lighttpd developer.  OP is likely trying to exec a directory, which is invalid.  The `/etc/lighttpd` spelling I used is accurate and intentional.  From where did you conjure that other, invalid spelling?

Comment: 1)  Execing a directory would cause the `exec` call to fail with an `IOException`.  The OP didn't get that.  2) I got the spelling from the text of the question.  In three places!   So where did you get *your* spelling from???   (Have you considered the possibility that the OP is doing what he is saying he is doing ... and using pathnames with a `.` at the start?)

Comment: @Stephen C, please review your comment.  "/etc/lighthttpd" is not currently present in the question.  "So where did you get your spelling from???"  I am a lighttpd developer.  I thought I already said that.  "/etc/lighttpd/" is used widely in lighttpd packages in many distros as a directory and contains the lighttpd config.

Comment: There is *nothing* in the official lighttpd source code build systems which creates an executable as you have spelled it, so whether OP is using /etc/lighttpd or ./etc/lighttpd, for that to be an executable would require someone who does not understand how "/etc" is conventionally used to have modified the lighttpd build.  That would be the blind leading the blind, but since op manually executing `./etc/lighttpd -D -f /etc/test.conf` worked for OP, that backwards case appears to hold.

Comment: As the lastest lighttpd release is currently lighttpd 1.4.66, wherever OP got the android build from is poorly maintained.

Comment: Kindly review the question and your answer.  `./etc/lighttpd` **IS** in the question in THREE places.  But you said `/etc/lighttpd` in your answer, and `/etc/lighttpd` **IS NOT** in the question.  And please review my first comment ... where I simply point out that you are talking about a path that is different to what the OP said he used.

Comment: @StephenC Your wrongly-invented typo "/etc/lighthttpd" in the first comment under this answer does not match "/etc/lighttpd".  I already acknowledged "/etc/lighttpd" vs "./etc/lighttpd" above, and pointed out that the source of then Android build, whatever it is, is poorly maintained, since lighttpd 1.4.58 is quite old compared to the current lighttpd 1.4.66.